# Load specific JSON data in one page by clicking an element on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, frontend

i want to load specific data from JSON to specific HTML page, by clicking button on another HTML page, using only jQuery and plain JS.
Example:

1st HTML page, first i need to display all products from JSON in  element with id="products":

```
<body>
<div id="products"></div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

2nd HTML page, when clicked on any product on 1st HTML page, specifications of that product need to be displayed on 2nd HTML page.

```
<body>
<div id="productDescription">

</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is sample JSON file:

```
[
 {
  "name" : "Asus",
  "model" : "laptopModel",
  "price" : 100000
 },
 {
  "name" : "HP",
  "model" : "laptopModel",
  "price" : 90000
 }
]
```

Thanks for any help, i need this for school project, that's why i'm able to use only JS and JSON.

Comment: Please edit your question. Your question says what you *WANT* to do, but not why you can't. Usually a question on StackOverflow asks something specific, so please explain what you have tried and be more specific about the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

Due to browser security blah blah, you can only read from a JSON file if that file is hosted (http/https), so this won't work with "file://" stuff run locally.

The first function downloads the json file, then turns it into a javascript data structure, then hands it off to the second function which builds the appropriate content and adds it to the page.

```js
const getPage = whichPage => {
  return fetch("path/to/yourfile.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => buildPage(whichPage, data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
};

const buildPage = (whichPage, products) => {
  if (whichPage === "products") {
    // do something with products to display a list of products
    products.forEach(p => console.log(p));
  } else {
    let product = products.find(p => p.name === whichPage);
    if (product) {
      // do something with product to display details
      console.log(product);
    } else {
      console.error("product not found [" + whichPage + "]");
    }
  }
};

getPage("products");

// or
// getPage("Asus");

// or
// getPage("products").then(() => getPage("Asus"));
```